# New to Web Scraping. How to extract title from div. How to put scraped data into Dataframe

Tags: python, html, jupyter

I recently started my jounrney for Data Science. I am using Google Colab's Jupyter for this task.

**First question**

I am trying to scrape data from an real estate website where I want to scrape Property Title, Price, Location, Beds, Baths for now.

Inspect from https://www.zameen.com/Homes/Lahore-1-1.html

```
<span class="_4720d1a0 "><span class="_0c8a5353 c1b40987"></span><span aria-label="Beds" class="b6a29bc0">5</span></span>,
 <span class="_0c8a5353 c1b40987"></span>,
 <span aria-label="Beds" class="b6a29bc0">5</span>,
 <span class="_4720d1a0 "><span class="_0c8a5353 fa6c05cc"></span><span aria-label="Baths" class="b6a29bc0">6</span></span>,
 <span class="_0c8a5353 fa6c05cc"></span>,
 <span aria-label="Baths" class="b6a29bc0">6</span>,
 <span class="_4720d1a0 "><span class="_0c8a5353 d2db01cb"></span><span aria-label="Area" class="b6a29bc0"><div class="_7ac32433" title="1 Kanal Luxury Bungalow For Sale In Lahore Dha"><div class="_1e0ca152 _026d7bff"><div><span>1 Kanal</span></div></div></div></span></span>,
 <span class="_0c8a5353 d2db01cb"></span>
```

I was able to pull Price, Location, Beds and Baths as a list

Finding Area from every property

```
property = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"aria-label":"Area"})
```

Finding price from every property

```
property = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class":"f343d9ce"})
```

but I was unable understand on how to extract Property Title when its in a span, then again in a div.

```
<span aria-label="Area" class="b6a29bc0"><div class="_7ac32433" title="1 Kanal Luxury Bungalow For Sale In Lahore Dha"><div class="_1e0ca152 _026d7bff"><div><span>1 Kanal</span></div></div></div></span>
```

Finding Title from every property

```
property = soup.find_all("div", class_="_7ac32433")
for i in property:
  print(i.get_text())
```

It just displays

```
PKR5.5 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR6.5 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR69.9 Lakh
5 Marla
PKR4.45 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR6.29 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR2.25 Crore
10 Marla
PKR55 Lakh
5 Marla
PKR5.28 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR1.4 Crore
5.5 Marla
PKR1.05 Crore
4 Marla
PKR5.15 Crore
1.1 Kanal
PKR6.35 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR1.15 Crore
5 Marla
PKR68 Lakh
3 Marla
PKR3.6 Crore
1 Kanal
PKR2.25 Crore
```

**2nd Question**

Once I am able to pull the required data from the URL. How do I create a dataframe and import these data into the dataframe for data science project? I am really new so I am unable to even construct the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of extracting areas, prices and titles and adding them to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zameen.com/Homes/Lahore-1-1.html'

page = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')

area_elements = html.find_all("span", attrs={"aria-label":"Area"})
areas = [el.text for el in area_elements]

price_elements = html.find_all("span", attrs={"class":"f343d9ce"})
prices = [el.text for el in price_elements]

title_elements = html.find_all("a", attrs={"class":"_7ac32433"})
titles = [el.get('title') for el in title_elements]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'area': areas,
    'title': titles,
    'price': prices
})

df.head()
```

Comment: Thabkyou so much